# Adding Kafka topics dynamically to consume from, without restarting my GoLang application

Tags: go, apache-kafka, go-gin

I have a Golang application that basically has Kafka consumers as its starting point. I fetch the list of topics to listen to, from the MongoDB at run time. However, each time I have to add a new topic to listen to, after adding to the Mongo, I have to restart the whole Golang application. The consumer is in the main file itself. I am using Confluent as a client. Is there a way to add more topics to consume from without restarting the application?

Comment: Which client are you using? [Confluent](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go)? [Sarma](https://github.com/Shopify/sarama)? [Segmentio](https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go)?

Comment: I am using Confluent

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried consuming to topic with `regular expressions`.

Example :

```
consume, err := kafka.NewConsumer(&kafka.ConfigMap{
                     "bootstrap.servers":  "server",
})

err = consume.SubscribeTopics([]string{"^.*_mypattern"}, nil)
```

Source : https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/issues/96

Also try setting this option when initializing the consumer `metadata.max.age.ms`. This will refresh the meta data to see if any new topics are available.

Answer (score 0):

A code snippet of that logic would help.

You can do so with [Mongo Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/).
For example, to watch changes of a collection, use the [`Collection.Watch()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo?tab=doc#Collection.Watch) method -

```golang
var collection *mongo.Collection

// specify a pipeline that will only match "insert" events
// specify the MaxAwaitTimeOption to have each attempt wait two seconds for new documents
matchStage := bson.D{{"$match", bson.D{{"operationType", "insert"}}}}
opts := options.ChangeStream().SetMaxAwaitTime(2 * time.Second)
changeStream, err := collection.Watch(context.TODO(), mongo.Pipeline{matchStage}, opts)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// print out all change stream events in the order they're received
// see the mongo.ChangeStream documentation for more examples of using change streams
for changeStream.Next(context.TODO()) {
    fmt.Println(changeStream.Current)
    // NewConsumer
}
```

And then create a [new consumer](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/master/examples/consumer_example/consumer_example.go#L45) or call the [`.SubscribeTopics()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka?tab=doc#Consumer.SubscribeTopics) whenever you update your collection and it's match your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

If the need is the consumer can consume message from the topic which is dynamic. I think you probably use Redis PubSub instead of Kafka.

Because when you need to consume from the topic that recently created, the consumer must reconnect again to the broker and it is so expensive when the new topic is frequently added.

I assume that the new topic describes a chat room/group. If correct, Redis PubSub Subscription is lighter than Kafka Consumer. You can use channel as the chat room/group.

Or you can use both Kafka and Redis PubSub, after consume a created room/group event from Kafka then set it as the channel of Redis PubSub and you can start to subscribe.